# Knox and Falcon on HDInsight

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

Are there any Microsoft Azure components which serves the purpose of KNOX and Falcon on Azure HDInsight.

Anyway, most of our workflows and scheduling will be through Azure Data Factory. We are more inclined towards azure components rather IaaS open sources.

So, does KNOX is available on HDInsight's latest version? alternatively, how Azure manages the secure gateway to HDInsight Clusters?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

[HDInsight Under Covers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2016/04/04/hdinsight-under-covers/) has some details on the HDInsight gateway. Essentially it is a HTTPS reverse proxy that provides access to common Hadoop Services.

What's your specific use case that is addressed using KNOX ?

[Ports and URIs used by HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-port-settings-for-services) may be a helpful doc too.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Currently, there's a third party systems on SAP HANA would like share the data within HDInsight. In this regard, if we setup  SAP HANA on azure as a IaaS,  then do we need Knox like gateway  ?     or Just Azure Virtual Network is more than enough ?

Comment: There are several ways of pulling in/ pushing out data from HDInsight. What would work best is if you could describe your use case in more detail.

Comment: For example, you could deploy an [empty edge node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apps-use-edge-node) in the cluster on which you could then install SAP HANA. You would then have no need to talk to the gateway.